# Invalid use of group function with if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the "Invalid use of group function" error using this SQL

```
SELECT 
  SUM(overTime) AS overTimeTotal 
  FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM(IF(
      SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid)) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000'),
      SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')),
      0)) AS overTime
    FROM hours
    WHERE user_id = :id
    AND month(starttid) = :selectedMonth) AS T
```

**Table structure and data:**

```
INSERT INTO `hours` (`id`, `user_id`, `starttid`, `sluttid`) VALUES
(89, 1, '2018-05-09 05:00:00', '2018-05-09 16:00:00'),
(90, 1, '2018-05-08 05:00:00', '2018-05-08 10:00:00');
```

So what i am trying with this sql is to get total overtime, but what happens is that when i have negative overtime, as in ID 90 (2:24:0000) - it substracts from total overtime, thats not what i want. I want to set SUM to zero, if overtime is negative - so that i only get the actual overtime. In this case the overtime result i expect is:
3:36:0000, but i get 1:12:0000. So i have been trying to get around this problem, and now i encounter the error described in the headline.

How do i do, what i want?

Comment: Why the php tag if there is no php code?

Comment: There's no 'table structure' here - and what does 7:24 represent?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte - Im not used to asking on stack, was just thinking that i use this in php, and it is a part of a php function, but you are right.

Comment: Would [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) be a viable alternative. _As in: `GREATEST(sum - something, 0)`._

Comment: @Strawberry - 7:24:0000 represent the overtime factor, after 7 hours and 24 minutes of work, the rest is counted as overtime.

Comment: @Uueerdo - I tried that, but could not make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are aggregating too soon.

Looks like you want to calculate overtime for each row, and then do the aggregate.

```
 SELECT SUM( 
          IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttid, h.sluttid) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttid, h.sluttid)  - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
            , 0
          )  
        ) AS overtimetotal
   FROM hours h
  WHERE h.user_id = :id
    AND MONTH(h.startid) = :selectedMonth
```

For testing, remove the aggregate SUM() function, and return other columns

```
 SELECT IF( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttid, h.sluttid) >= TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
            , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttid, h.sluttid)  - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
            , 0
        )  AS overtime

      , GREATEST(0,
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.starttid, h.sluttid)  - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')
        ) AS alt_overtime

      , h.id
      , h.starttid
      , h.sluttid
   FROM hours h
  WHERE h.user_id = :id
    AND ...
```

I'd also recommend using bare columns in the predicates in the WHERE clause, rather than running a function on the column. Use expressions on the literal side to return datetime datatype that matches the column datatype, e.g.

```
    AND h.startid  >= dt_month_begin + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
    AND h.startid  <  dt_month_begin + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```